# DAX Development: How to process a small portion of your data without importing millions of records in your machine? (SSAS Tabular Model)

Tags: ssas, dax, tabular

We are currently using Visual Studio 2015 to develop SSAS tabular models. Our tables consist of more than 100M records of data. Is there a technique or practice where in I won't need to import all of the 100M records to Visual Studio and just use a small portion of the data during development?

Right now, I just limited the data by selecting top 100,000 records in the VIEW that we are using and imported it to Visual Studio so that I won't processed 100M records in my machine. Once the project is deployed, we remove the SELECT TOP 100,000 from the VIEWS and reprocess them so that it would pick up the full dataset of 100M records.

Is there a better way to do this? Like using sample partition used for direct query cubes but for in memory cubes?

Is it suitable to use row level security to restrict the data sets when selecting from the view so my account returns a subset compared the agent service account?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the best practise is what you are already doing (and what I'm currently doing).

Start your cube with a small sample (between 1000 and 100000 rows for example). Once it's as you want it, deploy it. Then use SSMS to remove the sample and process your cube (with full data) and you will have a complete cube.

It's not really helpful because it's what your are doing now but it's the right way to do it.